# Trigger to update parent field with custom object data not populating

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, childrecords

I hope everyone is doing well. I'm new to SalesForce and have been trying to learn Apex for a few weeks without much headway. Our org has a custom object called Factor Data that is a related list at the bottom of the Account page, much like opportunity/contact/etc. We have a field called First Full Purchase on the Account page that is supposed to display the higher purchase of the first two purchases made. Purchase MTD is a field on each inputted Factor Data record. I have the following trigger, which passes ye ole syntax check, but gives me this error message:

PurchaseForBrokerBonus: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []: Trigger.PurchaseForBrokerBonus: line 27, column 1

I know I'm neglecting to list the IDs. I'm just not sure how to query for IDs on a custom object, or if I'm completely missing something. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for y'alls time and have a good one.

```
Set<Decimal> accountPurchases = new Set<Decimal>();
List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

for(Factor_Data__c fd :Trigger.new){
    accountPurchases.add(fd.Purchase_MTD__c);
}

accountPurchases.remove(null);

for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT MAX(Purchase_MTD__c) maxPurchase, Date__c
        FROM Factor_Data__c
        WHERE Purchase_MTD__c != null
            AND Purchase_MTD__c IN :accountPurchases
        GROUP BY Date__c
        ORDER BY Date__c ASC
        LIMIT 2]){


    accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(
        First_Full_Purchase__c = (Decimal)ar.get('maxPurchase')
    ));
}

update accountsToUpdate;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. First of all: you're not achieving what you want. You're are fetching the max value among the Factor Data with a value EQUAL to the one in the trigger. And you're limiting it to 2 accounts.

To achieve what you want, you'll need something like the code below. Note: replace Account__c with the name of the lookup field on the Factor Data.

```
List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
Map<Id, Decimal> maxPurchasePerAccount = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
Map<Id, Integer> accountPurchaseCount = new Map<Id, Integer>();

for(Factor_Data__c fd :Trigger.new){
    //get the id of all accounts affected
    accountPurchaseCount.put(fd.Account__c, 0);
}

//fetch all factor datas for the accounts concerned with no First Full Purchasebvh (if the account already has a First Full Purchase, there's no need to look again)
for(Factor_Data__c fc : [SELECT Purchase_MTD__c, Account__c
        FROM Factor_Data__c
        WHERE Account__c IN :accountPurchaseCount.keySet()
        AND (Account__r.First_Full_Purchase__c = 0 
        OR Account__r.First_Full_Purchase__c = null)
        ORDER BY Date__c ASC]){

    //Count how many factor datas were annalyzed for each account
    Integer count = accountPurchaseCount.get(fc.Account__c)+1;
    accountPurchaseCount.put(fd.Account__c, count);

    if(count > 2) continue; //We already evaluated the first two, no need to check further

    Decimal accountPurchase = maxPurchasePerAccount.get(fc.Account__c);
    if(accountPurchase == null) maxPurchasePerAccount.put(fc.Account__c, fc.Purchase_MTD__c); //evaluating the first one
    else if(fc.Purchase_MTD__c > accountPurchase) maxPurchasePerAccount.put(fc.Account__c, fc.Purchase_MTD__c); //if the second is higher, save this one instead
}

for(Id accId : maxPurchasePerAccount.keySet()){
    //reloop through the accounts to see wich one need to be updated 
    if(accountPurchaseCount.get(accId) >= 2){
        accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(Id = accId, First_Full_Purchase__c = maxPurchasePerAccount.get(accId)));
    }
}

update accountsToUpdate;
```

P.s.: as a best practice, on the first loop through the trigger new, add a check to know wich accounts to add to the set. Maybe you'll just want to do that when the Factor Data is approved or something like that

Comment: Hey Fernando, I apologize for the late response. Been away for a bit, but thank you so much. As always, I appreciate the help. I didn't realize I was limiting it to two accounts. I thought I was limiting the factor data to the first two entries, but that makes sense. It works great, I am just having trouble pulling the highest purchase if the second month's purchase is higher, but I will tinker around with that today and see if I can get it to work. Thanks again for all of the help. Still trying to get acclimated with all of this.